# Matlab png image distorted/quality loss

Tags: image, matlab, resize

I'm trying to display an image with Matlab. I tried different ways, but they all end up with the same result. Essentially:

```
I = imread('circletest.png','BackgroundColor','none');
imshow(I)
```

Outputs this:

[image]

When the actual image is just a red circle with transparent background. Does anyone know why the image gets deformed like this? It only happens if I specify no background color.

Also, about image resizing. I'm aware that Matlab resizes images by changing the matrix size, which necessarily implies a loss in quality. I'd really like to avoid that. Is there a way to make an image appear smaller in axes compared to other things? Can't matlab just output that same matrix size in a smaller area?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the alpha channel explicitly or set `'BackgoundColor'` to `[1 1 1]` (white)

```
[I map alpha] = imread('circletest.png','BackgroundColor','none');
ih = imshow( I );
set( ih, 'AlphaData', alpha );
```

Or try

```
I = imread('circletest.png','BackgroundColor',[1 1 1]);
imshow(I);
```

Comment: Thanks, the first part works. However for my application, I really needed to be able to position my image at specific locations over an axis and resize it while keeping the background transparent. From what I read online this isn't doable in Matlab, so I'll switch to another programming language.Good to know nonetheless!